# Массивы переменной длины (VLA) - это..?

Tags: c, массивы

Тут пишу программу, которая в общем-то сортирует слова в строке. В задании сказано, что:

> запрещено использование массивов переменной длины (VLA).

Если что, пишу я на СИ.

Я вот не совсем понимаю, что значит VLA. Это типо malloc и тому подобное? Или что-то еще?

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array#C99

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это когда вы пишете что-то вроде

```
int n;
scanf("%d",&n);
int a[n];
```

Т.е. массив, объявленный именно как массив, но размер которого определяется во время работы, а не во время компиляции.

С `malloc` — это несколько другое, это динамическое выделение памяти для массива:

```
int n;
scanf("%d",&n);
int *a = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
```

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое.